# Is the function $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(\sin x)}$ created only by dots?

Tags: trigonometry, continuity

I have this function

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(\sin x)}$$

Does it mean, this function is created only by dots?

$$\frac\pi2 + 2k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb Z$$

Because $\sin(x)$ must be equal or higher than $1$ to satisfy a condition, maximum value of $\sin(x)$ is $1$.

Does it also mean that this function is not continuous function on all its domain?

Is it removable discontinuity or that second kind?

Answer (score 3):

If you're working over the reals, then yes, this function is only defined for $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so its graph is the set of points of the form $(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, 0)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since the domain of $f$ is discrete, $f$ is continuous, but not in an interesting way. (Every function with discrete domain is continuous.)

Comment: It is directly continuous or removable discontinous?

Comment: @naruto25: What does 'directly continuous' mean?

Comment: that we can have this function continous without removing discontinuity, sorry if my question sounds stupid, starting with this kind of theory :)

Comment: can we calculate limit of this function in those particular dots, or limit does not exist?

Comment: @naruto25: Your question doesn't sound stupid, I just didn't know what you meant. This function *is* continuous, so there's no discontinuity to remove. The thing is, its domain is discrete (it's a bunch of isolated points), so you can't in any meaningful way talk about limits.

Comment: @naruto25 - You can take a limit _along the domain_ of $f$, which is this discrete set of points. Any limit using the standard $\varepsilon,\delta$ definition does not exist, because $f$ is not defined in a $\delta$-neighbourhood of any point.

Comment: Have another question. Well, this function have a discrete domain. And if I had an assignment in which I have to find all points of discontinuity of this function and classify them, what points are these?

Comment: @naruto25: Continuous functions have no points of discontinuity.

Comment: Can you please look on my other question, sir? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457563/points-of-discontinuity-of-second-kind